# jquery image fader, flash of unstyled content

Tags: jquery, css, fade, fouc

www.mymediaventure.com

i can't stop the images flashing up before they are put on top of each other and then the fader starts.

at the moment, im setting display to none in an inline style attribute on all but the first image.

then in the jquery im displaying all the images. but it loads the pictures then cycles through each without fading, and then goes onto the fading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, rather than setting `display:none`, set `opacity:0`, as your fading plugin uses opacity.

Hope that fixes it.